# Modern Zohar printing with older pagination

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, zohar

Has the Zohar been reprinted in such a way where the pagination follows the old printing? Meaning, it is common to find myriads of editions that where printed in modern times, but I have found that they often do not follow any external systems of pagination. The specific one I am referring to 1558 Mantua edition, where there are three parts (Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus-Deuteronomy), which make use of two-sided numbering (1a;1b). [See here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8)

Comment: https://www.nehora.com/zohar-hamefurash-dfus-vilna/

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/42098/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%96%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%A2-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93!) edition contains inside of the text the pagination used by the old Zohar, f.e. chelek 2, daf nun amud Bet.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Vilna edition (1882) and reprints thereof.

- [Part 1](https://hebrewbooks.org/14353)
- [Part 2](https://hebrewbooks.org/14355)
- [Part 3](https://hebrewbooks.org/14354)

Comment: do you meant offsets when you say reprints? I had thought the mosad harav kooks offset this, not sure thoguth

Comment: Scanned versions of it

Comment: I have a modern zohar and the old pagination is mentioned. Almost every edition is like this.